# tk messagebox import confusion

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, import

I'm just beginning to learn tkinter at the moment, and when importing messagebox I found that I must not really understand import statements.

The thing that confuses me is that:

```
import tkinter as tk

def text_box():
    if tk.messagebox.askokcancel("Quit", "Never Mind"):
        root.destroy()

root = tk.Tk()
button = tk.Button(root, text="Press the button", command=text_box)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

compiles fine, but pressing the button gives the error `'module' object has no attribute 'messagebox'`, while the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

...
    if messagebox.askokcancel("Quit", "Never Mind"):
...
```

...works without a hitch.

I get a similar error if I import with `from tkinter import *`.

The help for tkinter shows `messagebox` in the list of `PACKAGE CONTENTS`, but I just can't load it in the normal way.

So my question is, why...and what is it about importing that I don't understand?

Just thought I should mention—the code only works in Python 3, and in Python 2.x `messagebox` is called `tkMessageBox` and is not defined in `tkinter`.

Comment: +1 a good puzzler (for one who hasn't touched tkinter3).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`tkinter.messagebox` is a module, not a class.

As it isn't imported in `tkinter.__init__.py`, you explicitly have to import it before you can use it.

```
import tkinter
tkinter.messagebox  # would raise an ImportError
from tkinter import messagebox
tkinter.messagebox  # now it's available eiter as `messagebox` or `tkinter.messagebox`
```

Comment: O.k, that makes sense. Just a small question, might there be any problems putting `messagebox` into `tkinter.__init__.py` manually? I assume there was some reason the developers didn't.

Comment: Changing files in other packages isn't a good idea. Your code wouldn't run without that modifications and break on other machines or when the dependencies are updated. You should simply import what you need.

Comment: The problem would be that your code would be incompatible with _every other_ interpreter out there. There were reasons for dividing up the library, which are probably documented somewhere in the copious Python development notes.

Comment: Thanks, having only made local programs I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: I prefer `from tkinter import messagebox as tkMessageBox` because besides the resulting unqualified name being a little shorter, it's also the way many Python 2 scripts reverence it.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import sys

from tkinter import *
```

... and your code